Interpreting parameter distributions and 95% confidence intervals from Monte Carlo sampling
I have fit two datasets with a model (multiparametric biochemical network models) and these fits give estimates of many parameters, including one that I'll call A. The best-fit values for parameter A when using dataset 1 and dataset 2 are quite different, but I wanted to get a sense of how confident I should be in these parameter fits. I used a Monte Carlo sampling approach to do so, wherein I randomly varied the input data in these two datasets according to the associated estimates of measurement error. This gives me two distributions for the values of parameter A resulting from using dataset 1 or 2. These distributions are strongly overlapping (e.g. the 2.5th and 97.5th quartile with dataset 1 is [0.01,1.5] and the same for dataset 2 is [0.7,8]). Others in my admittedly very niche field have often used overlap in such intervals as evidence of a lack of a statistically significant difference.
However, if I apply something like a z-test to ask whether the mean estimates of parameter A when fitting to dataset 1 or dataset 2 are different from one another, the results come up as statistically significant. This seems reasonable when I consider that although there is large underlying uncertainty in what the true value of A is when fitting my model to dataset 1 or 2, given the large sample sizes I am working with from the Monte Carlo sampling, I can be quite confident that the mean values are precisely estimated and distinct from one another.
Would I be incorrect in interpreting this statistically significant difference in the mean estimates for parameter A as evidence that (at an alpha of 0.05) the value of parameter A is greater when the model is fit to dataset 2 than when fit to dataset 1? Am I committing some kind of basic logical error in my analysis?

Using overlap of quantiles to compare the locations of distributions is ad hoc and often wrong.  (This ought to be evident insofar as it doesn't account for the sample sizes at all.)  There are non-parametric comparisons based on order statistics, but that's not what your appear to describe in the first paragraph.  The moral is don't re-invent statistical procedures if you can help it: use the tried-and-true ones.

A few thoughts: you should definitely not condition on the number of resamples in your test. Requiring non-overlap of individual intervals is usually a much higher bar than the difference itself being different from 0 (on the order of the latter being tested at 0.005 rather than 0.05). And it's important to keep in mind what would be meaningful rather than just statistically significant; it sounds like your data might be compatible with a 7- to 70-fold difference between the two datasets but only domain knowledge can decide what the impact is of the answer being 0.5 rather than, say, 5.

PBulls, can you clarify what you mean by not "conditioning" on the number of resamples? Sorry for my ignorance here.
